# printing variables in pl/sql

Tags: plsql, oracle10g

I have the following code:

```
DECLARE
   v_hire_date DATE:='30-Oct-2000';
   v_six_years BOOLEAN;  
BEGIN
IF MONTHS_BETWEEN(SYSDATE,v_fecha_contrato)/12 > 6 THEN
      v_six_years:=TRUE;
ELSE
      v_six_years:=FALSE;
END IF;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('flag '||v_six_years);
END;
```

I want to print the value of the variable `v_six_years`, but I am getting the error:

```
ORA-06550: line 10, column 24:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to '||'
ORA-06550: line 10, column 3
```

How to print the value of the variable `v_six_years`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It seems you cannot concat `varchar` and `boolean`.

Define this function:

```
FUNCTION BOOLEAN_TO_CHAR(FLAG IN BOOLEAN)
RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
BEGIN
  RETURN
   CASE FLAG
     WHEN TRUE THEN 'TRUE'
     WHEN FALSE THEN 'FALSE'
     ELSE 'NULL'
   END;
END;
```

and use it like this:

```
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('flag '|| BOOLEAN_TO_CHAR(v_six_years));
```

Answer (score 9):

You can use below to print Boolean Value in PLSQL

```
dbms_output.put_line('v_six_years '||  sys.diutil.bool_to_int(v_six_years));
```

Answer (score 3):

`dbms_output.put_line` is not overloaded to accept a boolean argument.Simple one line answer would be

> dbms_output.put_line(case when v_six_years = true then 'true' else 'false' end );

Answer (score 1):

PL/SQL does not have a literal to represent boolean values. You will have to either convert the v_six_years boolean value to a string, or not use a boolean if you wish to print the value. PL/SQL booleans are great for logic but useless if you wish to display the value.

```
DECLARE
   v_hire_date DATE:='30-Oct-2000';
   v_six_years VARCHAR2(1);  
BEGIN
IF MONTHS_BETWEEN(SYSDATE,v_fecha_contrato)/12 > 6 THEN
      v_six_years:='1';
ELSE
      v_six_years:='0';
END IF;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('flag '||v_six_years);
END;
```

Or

```
DECLARE
   v_hire_date DATE:='30-Oct-2000';
   v_six_years BOOLEAN;  
   v_six_years_display VARCHAR2(5);
BEGIN
IF MONTHS_BETWEEN(SYSDATE,v_fecha_contrato)/12 > 6 THEN
      v_six_years:=TRUE;
      v_six_years_display := 'true';
ELSE
      v_six_years:=FALSE;
      v_six_years_display := 'false';
END IF;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('flag '||v_six_years_display);
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can print the contents of a variable using the `\echo` meta-command. From `man psql`:

> To retrieve the content of the variable, precede the name with a colon, for example:
>
> ```
> testdb=> \echo :foo
> bar
> ```

Answer (score -4):

```
declare
     v_line varchar2(40); --declare
begin
     v_line := 'Happy new year'; --assigns
     dbms_output.put_line (v_line); --display 
end;
```

Happy new year

Comment: Could you please [edit] in an explanation of why this code answers the question? Code-only answers are [discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/148272/274165), because they don't teach the solution. (Also, the code formatting is woefully lacking. Use Ctrl-K and **preview your post before submitting**.)

Comment: This does not answer OP question. `dbms_output.put_line` can take varchar2 argument but not boolean and that is the question.